# Who was C.H. Kao?

Tags: biochemistry, history-of-chemistry

I am editing a Wikipedia article about the Chen-Kao reaction that is used to identify ephedrine, but I am unable to find biographical info on C. H. Kao:

K.K. Chen and C.H. Kao - Ephedrine and Pseudoephedrine, their Isolation, Constitution, Isomerism, Properties, Derivatives and Synthesis - Journal of the American Pharmaceutical Association volume=15 issue=8 year=1926 pages=625–639

K.K. Chen and C.H. Kao, Pharm. Zentralhalle, Vol.70, p.27 (1929)

Comment: The basic info such as secondary name (Gao Chongxi), years of life (1901–1952), as well as occupation (professor of chemistry at Tsinghua University) are easily retrievable. Would you like to find something on the personal life, or anything else in particular? Probably someone with a solid knowledge of Chinese could help as well.

Comment: I would really like to reference an autobiography of some sort, so I or anyone else can write an article later on, possibly. Although full name will suffice

Comment: You will have to write to the library archivist at the University of Wisconsin at Madison. Write a formal email with all your proper affiliation and the purpose. Provide reference to several papers. Usually you will get a positive response.

Comment: @andselisk This is C.H. Kao, you mention Gao Chongxi. What is meant by secondary name in Asian (Chinese) culture?

Comment: @M.Farooq Hope it does not get to that. I mean that person has a reaction named after him, he should be mentioned somewhere...

Comment: According to the wikipedia article I'm editing it is either  Chung-Hsi Kao or Cheng-Heng Kao

Comment: Bear in mind that English transliterations of Chinese names have changed since the early 20th Century. The name "Kao" in the former Wade-Giles transliteration is spelled "Gao" in the modern pinyin transliteration. Same for Xi/Hsi and Chong/Chung. So "Gao Chongxi" and "Kao Chung-Hsi" are the same name transliterated two different ways.

Comment: @Andrew, interesting. But this gentleman C.H. Kao consistently uses this spelling in his papers so it should not be hard to locate him by contacting the UW library archivist.

Comment: @NikolaiFrolov, I have asked a couple of times, even from MIT archivists to get photos for a paper I was planning to write. They might charge a little bit but if you are serious, university library is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to consult "**The Study of Change Chemistry in China, 1840-1949
By James Reardon-Anderson, 2003.**" Andselisk found the right information about his professorship in Tsinghua University but his spellings and my search spellings are different. Our Chinese fellows can elaborate more on it.

As I mentioned in the comments, he studied from the University of Wisconsin, Madison. If you wish to seriously pursue his biography, you will have to contact the library archivist.

From Google Books one can see the relevant information:

On page 224 and 235

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a [Mandarin speaker](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65329/16683), I can assure you that Andrew's comment on the main post is entirely accurate. Maybe you could provide a link to this Google book... (or even better, type out/copy the text)?

Comment: Yeah, probably what I'll do. Even if I dig up his biography, one reference won't satisfy the notoriety requirements of Wikipedia

Comment: @NikolaiFrolov, For Wiki, you have to link the new entry on Dr. Kao with another existing entry. For example, notable U of Wisconsin aluminus or may be generate a name reaction page first.